# Maven add spring boot project as dependency in another project. why it needs classifier "exec"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I understand for adding spring boot project as dependency into another project it needs to be repackaged with classifier as "exec". Then it creates following two artifacts and i am able to import Test-project in another project.

- Test-project-0.0.2.jar (normal jar)
- Test-project-0.0.2-exec.jar (executable jar, put all classes under Boot-Inf)

But if i don't use classifier in spring repackaging goal and only configure "finalName" of artifact as "Test-project", then still it generates following artifacts but it gives compilation error while importing Test-project in another project:

- Test-project-0.0.2.jar (same normal jar as above)
- Test-project.jar (executable jar, put all classes under Boot-Inf)

Why maven is giving error in second scenario, when Test-project-0.0.2.jar exists and it's exactly same as jar generated in first scenario?

Here is the maven plug in configuration for second scenario:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>Test-project</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Using a spring-boot project as a usual dependency is not the best way to go. The `<finalName>` [does simply not exist for the plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/reference/html/#goals-repackage)

Comment: @khmarbaise: If i need to add spring-boot project as a dependency and control the artifact name (don't want to prefix it with "exec"), is that possible?

Comment: @surajbahl `Test-project.jar` is equal to `Test-project-0.0.0.jar` which is a completely different version than `0.0.2`. I'm not sure whether this is going to work. Why are you afraid of classifiers/qualifiers? It's just a file name after all. (And, BTW, `exec` is a suffix, not a prefix.)